# Slow brightness change on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, laptop, brightness, keys

I have a problem of too slow brightness change when I use the resp. keys on my keyboard.

When I push one of the keys just shortly it takes about a second for the brightness to decrease/increase. Pressing the key for a long time, in order to set the brightness to the lowest level, takes several seconds. And it takes even more time to increase the brightness since it still tries to decrease the brightness even when it's on the minimum level.

After that I **cannot change the brightness** for more than 10-15 seconds (depending on how long I pressed the button the first time).

My laptop is an HP Pavilion 15 n292-sr.

Comment: HP sucks. What happens if you use the settings, is there a similar delay when use the slide bar and click "Apply"?

Comment: If I use the slider from the popping-up menu in the top-right corner it works ok, although the slider jumping under the mouse and behave unstable, the brightness adjusts smoothly how it should.

Comment: Exactly same problem here using a Dell Inspiron 5548. Using slider the change is immediately, but using keys it taks several seconds do change.

Comment: I have [reported this as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/847001) (or actually resurrected a bug dating back to 2011). You may want to [report that you're affected too](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/847001/+affectsmetoo).

Comment: This is still an issue